# How to utilize useContext in expo router?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-context

I'm using the new Expo-Router version that uses a file based navigation
I used React's context API + useReducer hook to create a universal language context in the app
The problem is I have no idea where to wrap the context provider, there is no root component as I can see

my project structure:

```
app
    Dashboard.tsx
    index.tsx
    Login.tsx
    Profile.tsx
assets
components
    Button.tsx
    Drawer.tsx
    DrawerItem.tsx
    HR.tsx
    TextField.tsx
forms
    LoginForm.tsx
ts
    declarations.d.ts
.gitignore
app.json
babel.config.js
index.ts
metro.config.js
package.json
tsconfig.json
yarn.lock
```

index.ts

```
import "expo-router/entry"
```

Found this discussionon Github around the same problem, I have no _layout file though

Answer (score 5):

You must have a top level _layout file. Wrap it up with a provider and it should work for you.

```
<AppProvider>
      <Stack initialRouteName="home">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="home"
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
      </Stack>
</AppProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapp your Provider at the _layout

```
 <Provider>
   <Stack>
    <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
    <Stack.Screen name="modal" />
  </Stack>
</Provider>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).